# Handeling multiple User Interfaces with different bottom navigations in Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I am developing an app where there are different user interfaces depending on what kind of client u are. I wanted to create different Bottom Navigations depending on what type of user is logged in. The if- clause works, so the Log tells me the correct user type but I am getting a fatal exception because it tells me that the id of the second bottom navigation is not existent, but like the first one works. I now it's not the cleanest way to do so but I couldn't find a different way. Here is my code:

This is the main.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var homeFragment: HomeFragment
    lateinit var mapsFragment: MapsFragment
    lateinit var profil: Profil
    lateinit var chat: Chat
    lateinit var homeFoto: HomeFoto


    val COARSE_LOCATION_RQ = 101

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        lateinit var mDatabase : DatabaseReference
        val user = mAuth.currentUser
        val uid = user!!.uid
        var snapshot: DataSnapshot
        var anwender = "Suchender"


        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(uid)

        //Log.e("keyKey",mDatabase.database.getReference("Anwendertyp").child(anwender).toString())

        mDatabase!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists() && snapshot.child("Anwendertyp").value.toString() == "Suchender" ){
                    Log.e("keyKey",snapshot.child("Anwendertyp").value.toString())

                    //findNavController(R.id.suchenderNavigation)
                    var bottomnav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.BottomNavMenu)

                    bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
                        when (item.itemId) {
                            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                                homeFragment = HomeFragment()
                                supportFragmentManager
                                    .beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, homeFragment)
                                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                    .commit()
                            }

                            R.id.mapsFragment -> {
                                mapsFragment = MapsFragment()
                                supportFragmentManager
                                    .beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, mapsFragment)
                                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                    .commit()
                            }

                            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                                profil = Profil()
                                supportFragmentManager
                                    .beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, profil)
                                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                    .commit()
                            }

                        }

                        true
                    }
                }
                else{
                    setContentView(R.layout.startseite_fotografvideograf)
                    Log.e("key",snapshot.child("Anwendertyp").value.toString())

                   // Navigation.findNavController(HomeFoto().requireActivity(), R.id.navigation_home_fotografvideograf)
                    //findNavController(R.id.fotografNavigation)

//This is the variable that triggers the fatal exception
                    var bottomn = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavFoto)
                   

                    Log.e("heyo", bottomn.toString())

                    bottomn.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
                        when (item.itemId) {
                            R.id.navigation_home_fotografvideograf -> {
                                homeFoto = HomeFoto()
                                supportFragmentManager
                                    .beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, homeFoto)
                                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                    .commit()
                            }

                            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                                profil = Profil()
                                supportFragmentManager
                                    .beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, profil)
                                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                    .commit()
                            }

                            R.id.chatchat -> {
                                chat = Chat()
                                supportFragmentManager
                                    .beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, chat)
                                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                    .commit()
                            }

                        }

                        true
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
}
```

This is the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E8E8E8">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavFoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_fotograf" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the xml of the second bottom navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/BottomNavFotograf"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home_fotografvideograf"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:title="@string/profil" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/chatchat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
        android:title="Chat" />

</menu>
```

**Update**

This is the FATAL EXCEPTION I'm getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.discoverme, PID: 4430 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.toString()' on a null object reference at com.example.discoverme.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.kt:114) at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75) at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63) at – Luzie Ewert 19 hours ago    Delete
com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

like, it's so confusing. I know it has to be something with the id's or the fact that there can not be two bottom navigations in one layout but I can't help myself any other way and I can't tell where the first id of the first bottom navigation is coming from, because it is nowhere declared and if I'm using one of the id's I used in the xml's the app crashes and I am getting trhe same fatal (axception that tells me the reference is on a null object.

okay so update: I found the correct id. Apparently there have been two existing main.xml files and I had to delete one, but now I am only getting one of the bottom navigations, no matter what user (wether searching person or photographer) is logged in. The question is still, how can I separate them?
Here is the updated xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E8E8E8">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/BottomNavMenu"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavFoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttom_bg"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_fotograf"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"></com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, meaning that it just helps you to code. the outcome of your app isn't any different just because you're using android studio, so unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE, there's no need to use the tag

Comment: Can you please give us the exception you are getting?

Comment: like, it's so confusing. I know it has to be something with the id's or the fact that there can not be two bottom navigations in one layout but I can't help myself any other way and I can't tell where the first id of the first bottom navigation is coming from, because it is nowhere declared and if I'm using one of the id's I used in the xml's the app crashes and I am getting trhe same fatal (axception that tells me the reference is on a null object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed it by outsourcing the bottom navigations in new activities and starting those in the if-clause of the main activity.kt with new layouts.